# Spring security cannot loggin with current password

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, authentication, spring-security

I'm making with using spring and hibernate. In my database i'm having several users with 3 different roles. I'm using BCryptPasswordEncoder, in database i'm having users with plain password, encoded password and {bcrypt}encoded password, i'm having problem becouse when i type users with plain passwords i can login, when i type password encoded or {bcrypt}encoded i can't login.

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.spring.config;

import com.spring.service.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/managers/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/employees/**").hasRole("REGULAR_EMPLOYEE")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/").defaultSuccessUrl("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new UserDetails();
    }

    @Autowired
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

UserDetails.java

```
package com.spring.service;

import com.spring.entity.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class UserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService mUserService;

    @Override
    public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = mUserService.getUserByLogin(s);
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder userBuilder;
        userBuilder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(user.getAccountLogin());
        userBuilder.password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getAccountPassword()));
        userBuilder.roles(user.getRoleByRoleId().getRole());
        return userBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

plain-login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Log in</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style>
        .failed {
            color: red;
        }
        .success {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loginAction"
           method="POST">

    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">

        <i class="failed">Wrong data!</i>

    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">

        <i class="success">Logged out successfully!</i>

    </c:if>

    <p>
        Login: <input type="text" name="username" />
    </p>

    <p>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />

</form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `bCryptPasswordEncoder()` method be annotated with `@Bean` instead of `@Autowired` as you are declaring the bean not injecting it?

Comment: Spring version 5.0.3, it is just spring

Comment: Yogesh Badke i had @Bean in another class, i changed it but it doesn't help :/

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work... You are always encoding the password with BCRypt... You are encrypting the encoded password with bcrypt and are encoding the bcrypted password with bcrypt... Basically your `UserDetails` (the service thing) breaks everything but plain passwords.

Comment: Yeah you're right :), stupid mistake, thanks for help :)!